# Adding Image within a canvas circle

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am learning drawing canvas and now I have task. I need to add an image within the inner circle. The image position needs to be inside the circle. Also I attached the image with this post. My code are:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>

            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
            </canvas>

            <script>
            var c =  document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,100);

            var cicleT = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var dtx = cicleT.getContext("2d"); 
            dtx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
            dtx.stroke();
            dtx.fillStyle = "red";
            dtx.fill(); 

            dtx.fillStyle = "black"; // font color to write the text with
              var font = "bold 13px serif";
              dtx.font = font;
              dtx.textBaseline = "bottom";
              dtx.fillText("Bangladesh",50,50, 95 ,25);

            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe make an image of what you are trying to achieve in Photoshop and post here as well? Would be great to understand the task better.

Comment: This is just a test copy hence photoshop image won't be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ctx.clip](http://CanvasRenderingContext2D.clip()) to cut out the region you want to draw, and the following operation will be refined on the region, remember to restore when you complete the works that needs to be refined.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);

ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill(); 

// For safety, I move the draw image and draw text to image.onload.
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.onload = function() {
  var iw = image.width;
  var ih = image.height;
  var r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(iw/2, 2) + Math.pow(ih/2, 2));
  var ratio = 40 / r;
  var tw = iw * ratio;
  var th = ih * ratio;
  
  // Use the same ctx is ok.
  ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  // Save the current state of context, which is not clipped yet.
  ctx.save();
  
  // Clip by the stroke.
  ctx.clip();
  // Draw image.
  
  // 
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, iw, ih, 95 - tw/2, 50 - th/2, tw, th);
  
  // Restore the context, otherwise the text will also be clipped.
  ctx.restore();
  
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "black"; // font color to write the text with
  var font = "bold 13px serif";
  ctx.font = font;
  ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
  ctx.fillText("Bangladesh", 50, 50, 95, 25);
};

image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy3YL.jpg";
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: the full image isn't showing. I want to be able to display complete picture, doesn't matter if its not clear.

Comment: Edited, just give more param to drawImage and remember to calculate the target size based on original image's size.